# Integrity constraint issue in an inheritance relational model with MySQL 5.5

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-integrity

I have the following database relational schema that purports to model an EMP supertype together with two FULL_TIME_EMP and PART_TIME_EMP subtypes:

[image: database schema]
The problem I have is one of integrity i.e. I would like to make sure that a full-time employee can only have a corresponding row in the FULL_TIME_EMP table and similarly a part-time employee can only have a correponding row in the PART_TIME_EMP table.

As you will see from the screen captures below, this integrity constraint is not enforced.

Here is the EMP_TYPE table:
[image: EMP_TYPE table]

And the EMP table:
[image: EMP table]

The PART_TIME_EMP table: 
[image: PART_TIME_EMP table]

And finally the FULL_TIME_EMP table which presents the **integrity violation**!!
[image: FULL_TIME_EMP table]

Is there a way to enforce this integrity constraint by altering my database model design or do I have to resort to triggers?

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't *have* to resort to triggers, but it might help. Changing the structure will help a lot, but it normally relies on CHECK constraints. In MySQL, if you need a CHECK constraint, you have to write a trigger or add another table that uses a foreign key constraint.

You have an additional burden, in that a part-time employee could later become full time, and vice versa.

Here how I'd write it for a more standard SQL platform.

```
create table emp (
  emp_id integer primary key,
  emp_type char(1) not null check (emp_type in ('f', 'p')), -- FK in your schema
  emp_name varchar(50) not null,
  start_date date not null default current_date,
  unique (emp_id, emp_type)
);

create table full_time_emp (
  emp_id integer primary key references emp (emp_id),
  emp_type char(1) not null default 'f' check (emp_type = 'f'),
  foreign key (emp_id, emp_type) references emp (emp_id, emp_type),
  salary decimal(14,2) not null check (salary > 15000)
);

create table part_time_emp (
  emp_id integer primary key references emp (emp_id),
  emp_type char(1) not null default 'p' check (emp_type = 'p'),
  foreign key (emp_id, emp_type) references emp (emp_id, emp_type),
  rate decimal(14,2) not null check (rate > 0 and rate < 100)
);
```

In the table full_time_emp, these two constraints

```
  check (emp_type = 'f'),
  foreign key (emp_id, emp_type) references emp (emp_id, emp_type),
```

taken together prevent part-time employees from appearing in the full-time table. If the referenced row in "emp" contains 'p', the foreign key reference will fail; if you try to insert a 'p' into "full_time_emp", the check constraint will fail.

In this case, you can replace the check constraint with a one-row table and a foreign key reference. The table should contain only 'f'. (Or whatever ID number you use to represent a full-time employee.) Same thing works for "part_time_emp". So instead of the CHECK constraint, you could do *this* for full_time_emp.

```
create table full_time_emp_check (
  full_time_emp_type char(1) primary key
);
insert into full_time_emp_check values ('f');

alter table full_time_emp
add constraint full_time_emp_check
foreign key (emp_type) references full_time_emp_check (full_time_emp_type);
```

Changes for part_time_emp are similar. You might want a trigger on both those tables to make sure they never contain more than one row.

Even the checks on salary and rate *could* be implemented with additional tables and foreign key references. Be kind of like kicking dead whales down the beach, though. I'd probably implement *that* kind of range constraint with a trigger in MySQL.

IMHO, a CHAR(1) code is better than an integer for employee types. A human-readable code doesn't require a join.

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive and relevant answer!